# Triangle and Maxium value

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Given any triangle ABC with $a \ge b \ge c$ such that $\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{\sin^3(A)+\sin^3(B)+\sin^3(C)}=7$, what is the maximum value of $a$?

Answer (score 4):

Using the Sine Law, i.e.
$$\frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac{b}{\sin B} = \frac{c}{\sin C} = k $$

we find that the condition in the question is merely equivalent to $k^3 = 7$.

So $a = k \sin A \le k = \sqrt[3]7$.

Comment: Didn't you just say the equivalent of $1/2 + 2/2 + 3/7 = 6/11$?  And that the cube of the sum is the sum of the cubes?

Comment: @John Nope. Substitute for sin using k, and it will just cancel out. Equivalently, it works when the ratios are all the same.

Comment: Ahh, I see it now. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

since 
$$\sin^3{A}+\sin^3{B}+\sin^3{C}=(8R^3)^{-1}(a^3+b^3+c^3)$$
so
$$(8R^3)^{-}=\dfrac{1}{7}\Longrightarrow R^{-1}=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{56}}$$
so
$$a=2R\sin{A}\le 2R=\sqrt[3]{7}$$

Comment: That formula doesn't look dimensionally correct. What's R?

Comment: I don't follow the last assertion that $a = 2 R \sin A$.